# Segmentation fault while using sprintf in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am trying to open text files labeled with step number in C. While compiling with GCC compiler, I didn't get any error. But while executing, I am getting segmentation fault after 1016 steps. The output files are supposed to be saved in a folder named Config.

I have tried the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i,j,itime,nwarm;
    itime =0;
    nwarm = 25000000;

    while (itime<=nwarm){   
            printf ("itime =%d\n", itime);
            char filename[128];
            sprintf(filename,"./Config/%d", itime);
            FILE *fConfig=fopen(filename,"w");
            // Configuration print //
            for (i=0; i<100; i++){
                for (j=0;j<2;j++){
                    fprintf(fConfig,"%lf ",1.0);
                }
                fprintf(fConfig,"\n");
            }
        itime = itime + 1;

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to close the connection: `fclose(fConfig);` at the end of the while loop. then, are you sure the segfault is coming from `sprintf`? Finally, what do you want to do with the loops? Now you print two time "1.0" and then a line break and you repeat it 100 times...

Comment: @Chelmy88 It's occurring because the OP isn't closing the files. It could come from any function.

Comment: @JL2210 I guess so too, but since the question mention `sprintf`might be he knows, e.g. from gdb, that the segfault comes from here.

Comment: @Chelmy88 No, it's due to not closing the file. I tested it real quick and that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility: You open a file handle for every iteration of your loop, but you don't close it. Eventually you open too many file handles for the process, and `fopen` fails, returning a NULL pointer. But you don't check this pointer, and end up dereferencing it, causing a segfault.